# Keynote Animations - Can they be random?

Tags: keynote

I am stumped with a Keynote question (same problem in Powerpoint)—

I made a Jeopardy Board. I want people to choose questions randomly. When I click on the question, I have ANIMATED the 100, 200, etc, so the numbers fade away. Then I've hyperlinked to a slide with each question on it.

PROBLEM: Animations have to be set in a particular order! I want the questions to be chosen randomly. Do you know any way around setting up animations so they are not in order?

Any suggestions appreciated!! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to achieve this behaviour using AppleScript. The questions below touch upon shuffling and randomising slides in Keynote:

- [How to randomize Keynote slides](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10451371/how-to-randomize-keynote-slides)
- [Randomizing slides and duration for repeating Keynote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18475851/randomizing-slides-and-duration-for-repeating-keynote)

While Keynote is not intended for this kind of behaviour, you may have more success with other more [flash card like applications](https://discussions.apple.com/message/2363548#2363548).